# How to prevert activerecord write conflict in mysql database?

Tags: mysql, activerecord, yii

We use activerecord to manipulate the data in our database. But we encountered the trouble of write conflict. It's pretty seems like the read/write conflict in multi-thread programming. How in the situation of database, I don't whether I should lock the database just like lock memory access in multi-thread programming.

More specificly, is the following situation:

1 program A create an activerecord with the data read from database, then modified it.

2 program B create an activerecord exactly refers to the same row in database.

3 A write the data back to db.

4 B also write the data to db.

There comes a conflict.

We use yii frame to build our site, and use activerecord to access the MySql database.

Should we do all the stuff in our logic or use some database utility?

Comment: You should implement unique constraints which won't allow duplicate records. The instance of your program that creates unwanted duplicate will receive an error. Without more information, there's nothing else to advise (what's the db structure, what does it mean when you say that something refers to exactly the same record in db etc.).

Comment: activerecord fetch data from database and generate an object, exactly same record in db means they fetched the same row in database. We now prevent the conflict in our code, but since the logic comes more and more complex, I worried we may have trouble in future.

Comment: You can't safely prevent the conflict using code. Bear in mind there's  latency between YII and MySQL, even if it's 1 millisecond or 500 microseconds - it exists. You can (and probably will) end up with duplicates. This is a problem that has to be solved on db level.

Answer (score 1):

Putting all your stuff in a transaction and using `select for update` while selecting the row should do the trick.

`SELECT for UPDATE` will not let other threads select the same row until the thread in possession of that row commits the new version.

Comment: Using transaction cause another problem: if you fail in write to db. Then what should you do?

Comment: u rollback and start all over again.. any unhandled exception will issue the rollback automatically.

Comment: yes.. but this is pretty standard way of achieving such things.. depends on how long your process takes to come up with new values.. if that time is significant, you can do a normal select first up... come up with new values.. now do an select for update.. compare it with the previously selected value and decide accordingly if you want to overwrite or not.. this will reduce the lock time.